# Python 3. Сортировка словаря: вывести содержимое словаря в порядке возрастания

Tags: python, python-3.x

Имеется словарь из 10 элементов (некоторых может не быть), например:
`a = {2:5, 5:3, 7:4, 10:4}`

Требуется вывести содержимое словаря в порядке возрастания (неубывания) значений:

`5 3, 7 4, 10 4, 2 5`

Думаю, что данный код выглядит коряво:

```
a = {2:5, 5:3, 7:4, 10:4}
l = []
l1 = []

for i in a:
    l1.append(a[i])
    l1.append(i)
    l.append(l1)
    l1 = []

l.sort()

for i in range(len(l)):
    print(l[i][1], l[i][0])
```

Как его можно подправить?

Используется Питон 3.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы отсортировать данные по значению, можно воспользоваться конструкцией `list comprehension`

```
a = {2:5, 5:3, 7:4, 10:4, 8:7, 3:2, 0:0, 1:9}

def sort_dictionary_by_value(dictionary):
    list_of_sorted_pairs = [(k, dictionary[k]) for k in sorted(dictionary.keys(), key=dictionary.get, reverse=False)]
    # Так мы создаём кортежи (ключ, значение) из отсортированных элементов по ключу равному "значение ключа"
    # Также отсортированы будут и ключи, имеющие одно значение
    # "reverse = False" говорит, что перебор нужно делать в обычном порядке
    # Если нужно отсортировать значения в обратном порядке, то reverse можно сделать = True
    return list_of_sorted_pairs # после сделанных операций возвращаем получившийся список
```

Осуществить вывод, который вам нужен, можно так:

```
new_a = sort_dictionary_by_value(a)

for x in new_a:
    print(x[0], x[1])
```

Answer (score 4):

Классический вариант:

```
In [36]: from operator import itemgetter

In [37]: sorted(a.items(), key=itemgetter(1))
Out[37]: [(0, 0), (3, 2), (5, 3), (7, 4), (10, 4), (2, 5), (8, 7), (1, 9)]
```